# Python empty line and text marking

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using following code to pickup 10 random lines, however it's also pickups empty line. I just wanted to exclude empty line while doing selection. and also wants to mark selected line with * as prefix. so next time this code will not pickup any line which start with *.

```
import random  
task = 10  
while ( task >= 0 ):  
    lines = open('master.txt').read().splitlines()
    myline =random.choice(lines)    
    print(myline)  
    task -= 1  
print ('Done!')
```

Comment: Where do you want to mark it with a *?

Comment: @charlieg Beginning of selected line, may be also good idea to delete empty line if found during selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will randomly select 10 lines that are non-empty and not marked. The selected lines are printed out and the file is updated such that the selected lines are marked (prepended with `*`) and empty lines removed.

```
import random
num_lines = 10

# read the contents of your file into a list
with open('master.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = [L for L in f if L.strip()]  # store non-empty lines

# get the line numbers of lines that are not marked
candidates = [i for i, L in enumerate(lines) if not L.startswith("*")] 

# if there are too few candidates, simply select all
if len(candidates) > num_lines:
  selected = random.sample(candidates, num_lines) 
else:
  selected = candidates  # choose all

# print the lines that were selected
print "".join(lines[i] for i in selected)

# Mark selected lines in original content
for i in selected:
  lines[i] = "*%s" % lines[i]  # prepend "*" to selected lines

# overwrite the file with modified content
with open('master.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write("".join(lines))
```

Comment: to display lines, i used print (output) but output generate 10 line in continuous. anyway to print output line by line. also if possible, instead of ignoring empty lines, can we delete it.

Comment: I've updated the code to print out the selected lines instead of storing it in a list.

Comment: @user1582596 I've modified the code little -- since we want to eventually remove empty lines, the code now simply ignores empty lines when reading the original file. This makes things a little but cleaner.

Comment: Just a last one, after displaying lines, is there any quick way to export lines to a text file. ie. task.txt, TIA

Comment: When you run the script, simply redirect the output to the file. E.g. `python script.py > task.txt`. Note that you will no longer see the output in stdout. If you want to both see the output and redirect it to a file, use [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee): `python script.py | tee task.txt`

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of blank lines:

```
with open(yourfile) as f:
    lines = [ line for line in f if line.strip() ]
```

You can modify the stuff in the `if` part of the list comprehension to suit your fancy (`if line.strip() and not line.startswith('*')` for example)

Now shuffle and take 10:

```
random.shuffle(lines)
random_lines = lines[:10]
```

Now you can remove the lines you selected via `shuffle` with:

```
lines = lines[10:]
```

Rather than marking with a `*` ...

Comment: Isn't your `remove` loop equivalent to `random.shuffle(lines); lines = lines[10:]`?  You've already shuffled the lines in-place, so there's no order to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
lines = [line
           for line in open('master.txt').read().splitlines()
           if line is not '']
random.shuffle(lines)

for line in lines[:10]:
    print line
print "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

task = 10
with open('master.txt') as input:
    lines = input.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines] ## Strip newlines
    lines = [line for line in lines if line]  ## Remove blank
    selected = random.sample(lines, task)

for line in selected:
    print(line)

print('Done!')
```

Comment: The problem with names all your variables the same `lines` is that when you mean to type `lines` as in `[line for line in lines if line]` its easy to overlook a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random  
task = 10 

#read the lines just once, dont read them again and again
lines = filter(lambda x: x, open('master.txt').read().splitlines())
while ( task >= 0 and len(lines) ):  
    myline = random.choice(lines)
    #don't mark the line with *, just remove it from the list
    lines.remove(myline)    
    print(myline)  
    task -= 1  
print ('Done!')
```